# WordPress on Google App Engine Error During Setup

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, yaml

I'm trying to set up WordPress on Google App Engine for the first time.  I'm following [Google's tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress) and when I start the Development Server locally using the cmd:

```
C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine>dev_appserver.py C:\Development\myApp
```

I get the folowing error:

```
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: Unknown url handler type.
<URLMap
    auth_fail_action=redirect
    static_dir=None
    secure=default
    http_headers=None
    url=/wp-(.+).php
    static_files=None
    expiration=None
    upload=None
    api_endpoint=None
    script=None
    application_readable=None
    position=None
    login=optional
    mime_type=None
    require_matching_file=None
    >
  in "C:\Development\myApp\app.yaml", line 41, column 2
```

The 'app.yaml' is copied per in the tutorial but with the correct app i.d. added:

```
application: myApp ID
version: wp
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /wp-content/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: wordpress/wp-content/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-content/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))

- url: /wp-admin/(.+)
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/\1
  secure: always

- url: /wp-admin/
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/index.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-login.php
  script: wordpress/wp-login.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-cron.php
  script: wordpress/wp-cron.php
  login: admin

- url: /xmlrpc.php
  script: wordpress/xmlrpc.php

- url: /wp-(.+).php
 script: wordpress/wp-\1.php

- url: /(.+)?/?
  script: wordpress/index.php
```

this is the line that throws the error:

```
url: /wp-(.+).php
     script: wordpress/wp-\1.php
```

So, I dont know what to do from here - any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thnx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fix the yaml markup, there is only 1 blank space before the line that is giving you problems, check before the word 'script':

```
- url: /wp-(.+).php
 script: wordpress/wp-\1.php
```

When the second line should have 2 blank spaces like this:

```
- url: /wp-(.+).php
  script: wordpress/wp-\1.php
```

I was getting this error today too, very easy to miss.

Answer (score 0):

I found on another Q here on SO having a diferent issue but noticed that the line was missing from their app.yaml so I removed it and gave it a try:  It worked!